# Batch that convert TIMECODE to frame number

Tags: windows, batch-file

in a batch there is a envoroment variable called %timecode% that, if timecode exist and is defined, output a string of this type:

```
HH:MM:SS:FF
```

for example 01:32:21:05

In PAL mode, 25fps, I would like convert this timecode in his correspondant frame number, for rxample in the case of 01:32:21:05 is 138530

so the convert processing should output 138530

```
Another examples: 00:00:00:00 ----------------> 0
00:00:00:01 ----------------> 1
........
00:00:00:24 ----------------> 24
00:00:01:00 ----------------> 25
00:00:01:01 ----------------> 26
```

and so on
How can I do?

Comment: Can you show the code you have written so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
    set "frameRate=25"

    set "timecode=01:32:21:05"

    for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=:" %%a in (
        "100%timecode::0=: %"      
    ) do set /a "frame=((%%a %% 100)*3600 + (%%b0)*60/10 + (%%c0)/10) * %frameRate% + (%%d0)/10"

    echo %frame%
```

This code splits the timecode variable contents using the colons as delimiters. To account for zero prefixed fields (considered in octal form and problematic in the case of `08` or `09`), missing or bad formatted data, some "tricks" are used.

To correct the hour part, the input data is prefixed with `100` and this field will be handled modulo 100.

To handle the problematic zero prefixed fields, a colon followed by a zero in the input data is replaced with the same colon followed by a space.

To handle problems with missing fields, when doing the calcs all extracted data is suffixed with a zero (mutiplying it by 10) and the the result of the operation in this field is divided by 10

Comment: +1, But I don't see why a field would ever be missing, so no need to append 0 and divide by 10. Also, framerate does not need to be expanded since it is in SET /A. You could treat hour same as other fields if you copy the timecode value to a new variable with a colon prefix.

Comment: @dbenham, my fault on explaining it, the missing field can exist because the `:0` replacement for fields with only one zero (bad initial format). As the framerate value is known at parse time i leave to it the expansion instead of wait to the parse in the `set` evaluation. I doubted with the hour handling. At the end i decided to include an alternative way of handling the data.

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
SET "timecode=01:32:21:05"
IF DEFINED timecode (
 SET /a result=((1%timecode:~0,2%-100^) * 90000^) + ((1%timecode:~3,2%-100^) * 1500^) + ((1%timecode:~6,2%-100^) * 25^) + (1%timecode:~-2%-100^) 
) ELSE (SET "result=NOT defined")
ECHO result with timecode="%timecode%" is %result%

SET "timecode="
IF DEFINED timecode (
 SET /a result=((1%timecode:~0,2%-100^) * 90000^) + ((1%timecode:~3,2%-100^) * 1500^) + ((1%timecode:~6,2%-100^) * 25^) + (1%timecode:~-2%-100^) 
) ELSE (SET "result=NOT defined")
ECHO result with timecode="%timecode%" is %result%

GOTO :EOF
```

This should point you to a solution.

Note that the carets (`^`) are only required before the `)` because the `set` command is within a block. If you were to choose to `goto` a label if `timecode` was undefined, then the carets would not be required.

I've cosen to calculate the sum using a straight-forward method; prepending a `1` to the two digits, then subtracting `100` (which takes care of the `08/09` problem - a leading 0 is defined as octal and `cmd` will object to non-octal characters) The routine could be made simpler by the use of `magic numbers`, but that would require more explanation.