# calculate number of frames of video by the duration value in PAL mode

Tags: batch-file, audio, video

I have a file called ffprobe.log that contains this text:

```
ffprobe version N-63113-g72dcd48 Copyright (c) 2007-2014 the FFmpeg developers

Duration: 00:00:35.37, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 60268 kb/s
```

I should do this operations:

1) isulate the value of duration starting from the notation HH:MM:SS:milli  hous:minutes:second:millisec

2) multiply the entire value by 25 (video pal mode) so, for example in this case of 35.37 (seconds) x 25 (frames) == 884,25

3) rounding down = 884

4) put the value 884 in a variable %number_Of_Frames_at_25fps%

Ho can I do it? thanks a lot!

(NB: frame0 + frame1 + frame2 + ... ... + frame24 == 1 second)

Comment: Just because something runs on the command line or uses a batch file, or any other "black box with text in it" *doesn't* mean it is DOS!

Answer (score 0):

With some changes to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26272495/2861476), but with the same idea

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
    set "frameRate=25"

    for /f "tokens=2" %%a in ('
        type ffprobe.log ^| findstr /b /c:"Duration:"
    ') do set "timecode=%%a"
    set "timecode=:%timecode:.=:%"

    for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=:," %%a in (
        "%timecode::0=: %"      
    ) do set /a "number_Of_Frames_at_%frameRate%fps=((%%a00)*3600 + (%%b00)*60 + (%%c00) + (%%d0)/10 ) * %frameRate% / 100"

    echo %number_Of_Frames_at_25fps%
```

Comment: please consider only a .txt file called duration.txt that contains: 0:00:35.368667 please can you the only routine to convert this notation in frame_number?

Comment: @user3572760 remove `"tokens=2"`, change `'type ... ^| findstr...'` to name of file, change `(%%d0)/10` into `(%%d0)/100000`